# Reformat bank account sortcode in SQL

Tags: sql, typeconverter

I'm a bit of a novice so be gentle with me.

I'm looking to convert bank account sortcode data (6 digit numeric eg "123456") into the following format "12-34-56"). That is inserting hyphens / dashes between each pair of digits retrieved from the database.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which SQL dialect and DB are you talking about? What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, then
You can simply try like,

```
SELECT 
CAST(SUBSTRING(CODE,1,2) AS VARCHAR)+'-'+
CAST(SUBSTRING(CODE,3,2) AS VARCHAR)+'-'+
CAST(SUBSTRING(CODE,5,2) AS VARCHAR)
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

OR

You can use,

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(CODE,'##-##-##') 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Perfect. Yes I am using SQL Server and that did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the format function

```
declare @s int = 123456;
select format(@s,'##-##-##');
```